# Force a directive to always load prior to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a UI issue. There is a misfire in load order that happens 1 out of every 50 times or so. The Angular JS app has a shared directive as a navigation button panel and that part is used by most of the other controllers.

1. Normal firing order

   - ButtonController.init() <--Set all buttons to hidden
   - EditGroupController.init() <--Set all buttons based on service call data
2. When the problem happens firing order

   - EditGroupController.init() <--Set all buttons based on service call data
   - ButtonController.init() <--Set all buttons to hidden

In scenario 2 above the EditGroupController tries to invoke an event on the ButtonController via:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('setHeadersButtons', buttons);
```

However, when I trace into the angular internal code there is a logic branch where it looks for a registered listener with that name and it does not find one to fire because the module has not been loaded.

I remember in an Angular 7 app I used the APP_INITIALIZER to force a core piece to load first. Sorry if my wording is not precise front end / angular is not my specialty and this somewhat fell into my lap. Is there a way to ensure a directive in Angular JS is loaded before any other pieces?

There is an app.route.js, can I force the directive to load there?